# form field needs an array

Tags: php, forms, select, innerhtml

I will get right into it. I have an html page with a select form element tag named "location" and I coded a button to be able to add another select tag form field in case users need to indicate multiple different locations when submitting the form. My problem is I cannot seem to add an additional select form field with a different `name=""` ideally I would like `name="location0"` and when user clicks again to add another select form field it should be `name="location1"` and so on...

I tried the push() function with this code:

```
<button onclick="add_fields()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var location= ["location"];
document.getElementById("invoice").innerHTML = location;

function add_fields() {
    location.push("+")
    document.getElementById("invoice").innerHTML = location;
}
</script>
```

but that did not work either. My implementation of this code is the problem I'm sure.

I provided my code in a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyzfbnqr/), the script is included in the html section, only worked in the html section (weird), any help is appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "location[]" as the selects name and then when you receive the data via $_POST, that will be an array with the distinct values.

If you put something like this, you will see that:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    //$locationArray=$_POST['location'];

}
?>
```

$_POST['location'] will be an array with the distinct values in the distincts positions

Comment: i went a different route but decided to give you the points for taking the time to give this answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what I need to do?

```
  if (isset($_REQUEST['location']) && is_array($_REQUEST['location'])) {
  $location = $_REQUEST['location'];

  foreach ($locationas $location) {
    print $location;
  }
}
```